# Is there any way by which one can increase the output height in hydraulic lift?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

For example:

If the lift cylinder were $25 \text { cm }$ in diameter and the small cylinder were $1.25 \text { cm }$ in diameter, then the ratio of the areas is $400$, so the hydraulic press arrangement gives a multiplication of $400$ times the force. To lift a $6000 \ N\  $car , I would have to exert only $6000 N/400 = 15 N$ on the fluid in the small cylinder to lift the car. However, to lift the car $10 \text{ cm }$, I would have to move the oil $400  \times 10 = 40 \text{ meters }$.

Is there any way possible by which even without changing the area of the lift cylinder such that I could achieve the height of $10 \text{ cm }$ lift by moving the oil for less than $40 \text { meters }$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you change the diameter of the smaller cylinder, it is not possible. Doing so is a direct violation of the Law of Conservation of Energy. In fact, if we consider realistic situations, we might have to move the oil *more* than 40 metres, accounting for energy losses.

The hydraulic lift does not really help us reduce the "work". The benefit is that you need to apply (generate) lesser force.